# Travis encrypt vars not decoded properly gibberish=[secure]

Tags: git, encryption, travis-ci, travis-ci-cli

I'm trying to use some encrypted vars with travis-ci.com and they are not decoding properly when travis executes a build from a commit.  You can see when it does the export it's just a gibberish VAR.

**The Setup:**

1. Running on Ubuntu: buster/sid
2. I've installed ruby-full
3. I've gem installed travis: 1.8.8
4. I've pulled my repo and I'm doing the encryption commands in the folder with .travis.yml
5. It asked me to verify it had the proper repo the first time I ran the encrypt command.
6. I expect I'm getting the proper public key, but it sure doesn't look like it.
7. This is all happening in a docker container.
8. I'm committing to master.  No pull request.

**Other things I've tried or screwed up already:**

1. Single quotes around the var.
2. Multiple vars or missing dash.  Having multiple vars changes the format slightly in that they have a "-" in front of secure.  The line would then look like:  `- secure INXfNQealZn84xzQ6M0g...`
3. Ran the encryption in the wrong repo folder.

**Commands used to generate MYVAR:**

```
root@31ee1eba15d3:~/tigelane/stuff# travis encrypt MYVAR="somestuff" --add env.global
root@31ee1eba15d3:~/tigelane/stuff# tail -3 .travis.yml
env:
  global:
    secure: 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
```

**Output I get in the Travis Job log:**

```
Setting environment variables from .travis.yml
$ export sqI72mUtHwsyUxmgpoGVoyZcJrg=[secure]
```

**Output I expected in the Travis Job log:**

```
Setting environment variables from .travis.yml
$ export MYVAR=[secure]
```

Answer (score 1):

I know the solution, at least in my case. When you use travis encrypt. You should specify whether you're running on the travis-ci.com domain or not. If you are and using like a public github linked to a travis integration. You need to use the --com parameter

Example:

```
travis encrypt --com "MYVAR='something'"
```

This gives the correct output. In the manual it doesn't give enough status to this flag, so I glossed over it at first not really sure what it did. Apparently it's because it has a different encryption key.

Comment: Huge thanks, I had literally no idea, the official doc should point this out because it's not obvious at all.

Answer (score 0):

You've forgotten a dash:

```
env:
  global:
    - secure: INXfNQe…
```

See https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#defining-encrypted-variables-in-travisyml

Comment: Thanks phd.  I used the --add command line argument, it's not a copy and paste.  The dash only appears when you add more than one secure var.   Either way, I added the dash and there is 0 different.  Same error and output in the log file.  I'll edit the question to make it a little more clear that it's bee tried with a dash.

Comment: I tried both ways and it didn't work for me. I've tried various methods to get the information to decrypt properly. Nothing worked.